# how to move files from multiple servers to multiple different directories

Tags: file, csv, powershell, move, remote-server

I am looking to move log files from multiple remote servers to one remote server that has a different directory for each different remote server I am copying files from.

I put together a basic one then I realised more problem and not being amazing with PowerShell I am a bit stuck.

Is it possible for me to use a CSV file or a notepad to list all of the different directories and match them up with the remote servers I am copying from?

```
$server_names = Get-Content "C:\ServersList.txt"
Foreach ($server in $server_names) {
    Copy-Item "\\$server\D$\*.log" -Destination "\\" -Recurse
}
```

Comment: So the destination server will just have a folder that you can copy to? `-Destination \\logServer\logs\$server -Force`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, not sure how that marries up with the original file that is being copied.  So the file being copied is in \\hostname\d$\gcti\application_name\logs and is moving to something like \\hostname\var\opt\Logs\application_name.  Both need to match up so the right log file is being place in the right directory.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by match up. Do the logs between different servers have unique hostnames? Do you need to change the name when it is copied so that you know which host it came from? My suggestion will place the file in a folder that has the same name as the server. Also your `copy-item` will copy all .log files...

Comment: What you want is certainly possible. The question is: is it necessary? Your question shows what you have (which is good), but doesn't say much about where you want to go, or what problem you have getting there.

Comment: You so we have x amount of applications, those applications generate logs.  The space on the application servers are limited and we need the logs for troubleshooting.  So we are looking to move these files either every hour or every 24 hours.  The files are moved to a mount on a SAN, the folder structure is a folder\directory for each application.  So when moving application A log files to the SAN, I need it to go into the folder for Application A log files and so on

Comment: Are these scattered over the filesystem or in a single folder? Do you need to select specific logs for any given application, or can you just move all files for an application?

Comment: files for each application are in different remote servers, I would be copying anything that has the extension .log.  Then moving them to a SAN storage array which has numerous different directories named after each application.